# Copy file link on the contextual menu

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

In the windows explorer contextual menu I would like an item : "Copy file link to the clipboard". Is there a way to add this via the windows registry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check this article: [**Copy File Path and Name using Windows Explorer Context Menu Extensions**](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=168&t=Copy_File_Path_and_Name_using_Windows_Explorer_Context_Menu_Extensions)

Instructions and registry entries to modify are described in it.

Comment: +1 - How is this not higher rated??? I've lost hours of my life because I didn't know this and did it with a two step process. Every time I think to myself..."there must be a better way".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Snark, that worked great. I just had to make a small modification.

If anyone has a permissions issue (non-admin privileges on a work computer) you can follow the directions in the link in Snark's comment, but then in the .reg files replace

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

with

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

It will apply the settings on a per-user basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).